Thermal propagator for free phonons evaluation
I'm trying to evaluate the thermal propagator for free phonons $$-D(\bar{x}\tau, \bar{x}'\tau') =  \left\langle \mathcal{T} \varphi(\bar{x}\tau)\varphi(\bar{x}'\tau') \right\rangle $$
where its Fourier-Matsubara component ($\omega_k = ck$ with $c$ longitudinal velocity) is $$D(k,i\omega_n) = \frac{\omega_k}{\omega_n^2 + \omega_k^2}\theta(\omega_D - \omega_k).$$
First of all I wrote the propagator in $(k,i\omega_n)$ space:
$$D(\bar{x}\tau, \bar{x}'\tau')= \int \frac{d_3k}{(2\pi)^3} exp(i \bar{k}\cdot(\bar{x}-\bar{x}')) \frac{1}{\hbar\beta}\sum_\omega exp(-i\omega_n(\tau-\tau'))\frac{\omega_k}{\omega_n^2 + \omega_k^2}\theta(\omega_D - \omega_k)$$
and using the Matsubara sum for Bosons
$$\frac{1}{\hbar\beta}\sum_\omega \frac{1}{\omega_n^2 +x^2}= \frac{1}{2x}cosh(\frac{\beta}{2}x)$$ we obtain $$D(\bar{x}\tau, \bar{x}'\tau')= \frac{1}{2}exp(-i\omega_n(\tau-\tau')) \int\frac{d_3k}{(2\pi)^3} exp(i\bar{k}\cdot(\bar{x}-\bar{x}')) cosh(\frac{\beta}{2}\omega_k)\theta(\omega_D - \omega_k).$$
Now we can use spheric coordinates:$$D(\bar{x}\tau, \bar{x}'\tau')= \frac{1}{2}exp(-i\omega_n(\tau-\tau')) \int_0^{\omega_D/c}\frac{dk}{(2\pi)^3} \int_0^\pi d\theta\int_0^{2\pi}d\phi k^2 cosh(\frac{\beta}{2}ck)sen\theta exp(ikrcos\theta).$$
Computing integrals in $d\phi$ and $d\theta$ we obtain:$$D(\bar{x}\tau, \bar{x}'\tau')= \frac{1}{2(2\pi)^2}exp(-i\omega_n(\tau-\tau')) \frac{1}{r} \int_0^{\omega_D/c} dk k sen(kr) cosh(\frac{\beta}{2}ck). $$
I think it is more useful taking limits of this integral, for example $T\rightarrow0$ and $T\rightarrow \infty$.
In the first case, if $T\rightarrow0$ then $\beta\rightarrow \infty$. Expanding $cosh$ and keeping only small $k$ contribuites follows that $$D(\bar{x}\tau, \bar{x}'\tau') \approx exp(-i\omega_n(\tau-\tau')) exp(\frac{\beta}{2} \omega_D)), $$ which is exponentially increasing in this limit.
I was wondering if this makes sense. I thought that it is correct since in BCS theory phonon fluctuations are dominant.
Thank for the help.

When you evaluate the Matsubara sum over $\omega$ you need to include the exponential factor with $\tau-\tau'$.
